# how to extract in between characters from a group of characters using shell scripting

Tags: shell

My curl method returns a unstructured json as of like-

```
result":{"fields":[{"position":1,"tokenized":false,"startOffset":0,"endOffset":0,"primary":false,"fieldBusinessName":"id"...
```

Now from that json i want to know the value of primary whether it is true or false .
As the returned json has all words concatenated, i am thinking of taking the characters in between "primary": and ,"fieldBusinessName" . This will solve my problem. Is it possible.

Note : It is a unparsed json and it has all words concatenated

Comment: Usual advice: use a proper parser instead of hacking a regular expression (a language that fundamentally cannot parse JSON). Please show a complete sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple pattern matching:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp="${1##*primary\"\:}"
result="${temp//\,*/}"

echo "primary is: $result"

exit 0
```

Usage:

```
$ ./primary.sh 'result":{"fields":[{"position":1,"tokenized":false,"startOffset":0,"endOffset":0,"primary":false,"fieldBusinessName":"id"...'
```

Result:

```
primary is: false
```

Comment: did you single quote the input? Look at my usage. You must put that long string in single quotes `'`. Works fine here. Also did you make the script executable? if not, then do `bash primary.sh 'long string'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk`:

```
awk -F: '$1=="\"tokenized\""{print $2}' RS='[,{}]' file
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Some shells like Bash or Zsh have regex matching capabilities.

Here is a Bash solution:

```
json="$(curl url)"
[[ $json =~ primary\":([a-z]+),\"fieldBusinessName ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```